# Filter error when using Isotope and Webpack

Tags: webpack, filter, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope with webpack. Isotope is being instantiated, but filtering doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');

export const Advices = {
    init: function(){
        var $iso = new Isotope( '.advices-list', {
            itemSelector: '.advice-item',
            percentPosition: true,
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            filter: '*'
        });
        $('.adv-select').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            const $target = $(this).data('target');
            if($target == 'all') {
                $iso.Isotope({ filter: '*' });
            } else {
                $iso.Isotope({ filter: $target });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, when the page loads, the isotope is working, but when I click, I get the error:

```
$iso.Isotope is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the **proto** of the isotope instance $iso, I don't see a function called isotope, but I see a function called arrange, and it works !

So, inside the click function, use arrange() instead:

```
$('.adv-select').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const $target = $(this).data('target');
    if($target == 'all') {
        $iso.arrange({ filter: '*' });
    } else {
        $iso.arrange({ filter: $target });
    }
});
```

I don't know why, but it works.